# Creating a table and saving it as a .mat file in matlab

Tags: matlab

"Define the surface representation (i.e., a vertex table and a surface table) for a tetrahedron
with edge lengths V1V2 = V1V3 = V1V4 = a = 1. The first vertex
V1 is placed at the origin, the edge V1V2 lies on the x-axis, the edge V1V3 lies on the
y-axis, and the edge V1V4 lies on the z-axis. Save the vertex table and the surface table
into a file vertexQ2.mat."

I must answer this question for a homework assignment. I am completely new to matlab apart from viewing the demos and reading the basic tutorials. These however have not helped with this question.
I know what the vertex and surface tables are but the part i am struggling with is creating these tables in matlab then saving them as a .mat file.
I have tried to do something like this:

```
>> v1 = [0 0 0]

v1 =

     0     0     0

>> v2 = [1 0 0]

v2 =

     1     0     0

>> v3 = [0 1 0]

v3 =

     0     1     0

>> v4 = [0 0 1]

v4 =

     0     0     1

>> T = table(v1,v2,v3,v4)
??? Undefined function or method 'table' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

but this has failed to create the table. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using a version of MATLAB that does not support `table`.  `table` was introduced in R2013b.  You are using a version of MATLAB that is older than R2013b.  The only way for you to get `table` working is if you upgrade your version of MATLAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an older version of MATLAB that does not support `table`.  `table` was introduced in R2013b, and so you are probably using a version that is R2013a or older. The only way for you to get `table` working is if you upgrade your version of MATLAB.

However, if you want something that kind of mimics `table`, you can create a structure with fields `v1,...v4`:

```
T.v1 = [0 0 0];
T.v2 = [1 0 0];
T.v3 = [0 1 0];
T.v4 = [0 0 1];
```

This way, you can access the field within your "table" by using dot notation:

```
out = T.v1; %// or T.v2, T.v3, T.v4
```

Similarly, you can just create a matrix as it looks like all of the fields are vectors of the same length:

```
T = [0 0 0; 1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1];
```

To access the field you want, just extract out a particular row:

```
v1 = T(1,:);
v2 = T(2,:);
v3 = T(3,:);
v4 = T(4,:);
```

Comment: @RoryPerks - My pleasure.  If you don't mind, accept my post to signify to the SO community you no longer need help.  Good luck!